# Input changing border-radius + suggestion

Tags: jquery, html, css

to make it short :
I have a picture, set border-radius to it, got a input type number, which should change the border-top-left  on keyup( also suggest if there s a better way to do it than keyup ). However code does not work for some reason. I've tried debugging and it seems  it take the value properly, tried setting particular border-top-left-radius like 35px and it works as well, but when i set it to the value of "x" it does not work.  Here s a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fwsd8td1/   - the jquery in the JSfiddle does not work for some reason.

Here's the code:

HTML :

```
<main>
        <div id="gallery">
        <img src="http://thumbnails.cbc.ca/maven_legacy/thumbnails/822/983/raw-obama-prince-george-050116.jpg" alt="" id="pic" />

<input type="number" name="TLR" min="0" max="50" " />
        </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main div#gallery > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

#pic {
    border-radius: 250px;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("input[name='TLR']").on('keyup', function() {
    var x = $("input[name='TLR']").val();
    $("#snimka").css('border-top-left-radius',x);

    console.log(x); /* debug */
});
```

Note that x should get  "px" as default

Comment: _“Note that x should get "px" as default”_ – where from? Your `x` is just the value of the input field, and that doesn’t include any unit. You need to specify the unit yourself when you assign the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 :Using Javascript in keyup event**

```
    $("input[name='TLR']").on('keyup', function() {

    var x= $("input[name='TLR']").val();

    //$("#pic").css('border-top-left-radius',x);
 document.getElementById("pic").style.borderTopLeftRadius  = x+'px';

});
```

Click Here For [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/cmw2juoa/)

**Method 2 :Using Jquery**

```
$("input[name='TLR']").on('keyup', function() {

        var x= $("input[name='TLR']").val();

         $('#pic').css('border-top-left-radius', x+'px');

    });
```

Click Here For [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/1tkcp4kt/)

Comment: Wow thanks, I saw a few  other similiar questions here on stackoverflow and they said  'px' s a default. Does make sense when im taking the value of an input though... I feel dumb. Thanks for the help !